# Find nearest Image on A tag Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this list and I want to change image on a tag clicked. How can I do that???

```
 <ul>
        <li class='Root'>
           <img src='icon_plus.png' /><input type='checkbox' /><a href='#'><span>sth</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='Root'>
          <img src='icon_plus.png' /><input type='checkbox' /><a href='#'><span>sth</span></a>
        </li>
 </ul>
 <script>
     $('.Root a').click(function () {
             //How Can I do that????
     });
</script>
```

Comment: it's not clear want you want ,can you elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('.Root a').click(function () {
    var $img = $(this).siblings('img');
    $img.attr('src', 'newimage.png')
});
```

```js
    $('.Root a').click(function() {
      var $img = $(this).siblings('img');
      $img.attr('src', 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='Root'>
    <img src='icon_plus.png' />
    <input type='checkbox' /><a href='#'><span>sth</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class='Root'>
    <img src='icon_pluss.png' />
    <input type='checkbox' /><a href='#'><span>sth</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I Want To check Image src and change it on if:                                              if (src is=="icon_minus.png" ) {  img.src="icon_plus.png";   }
                    else {  img.src="icon_minus.png";}

Comment: You need to add that to your question.

Comment: Edit your question by clicking the edit link below the tags and update it.

Comment: I change my function in question